# Update component datas by input value

Tags: angular, observable

This is a example component

```
export class childComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input idToCheck: number
  public myData;

  constructor(private myService:MyService){}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.myService.getData(id).subscribe(data-> {
      this.myData = data;
    })
}
```

Is it the best way ? Because the subscribe will be called each time input changes may i put it on onInit function ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Obivously it depends on your needs. Do you need to request your API on every ID change ?

Comment: If you want to update data **only** when `@Input` value changes, then you need to use `OnPush` change detection strategy. See: https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: @HarunYılmaz he can also use `ngOnChanges` without the on push strategy.

Comment: Of course he can. But it is why I made  "only" bold.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `setter` function in this case, like:

```
@Input() set idToCheck (id: number) {
    // ignore the value if id is undefined
    if(id == undefined) return;
    // call the service function when the id is passed
    this.myService.getData(id).subscribe(data-> {
      this.myData = data;
    });
}
```

So, these lines will be called each time the parent component change the value of **idToCheck** input.

I think this is simpler and clearer way.

Read more about [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).